# Karma Coverage - Angular 2 - Typescript - System JS Test Shim

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I have karma coverage generating a report based upon the items that are imported into my spec(unit)tests via systemjs.

I am interested in getting an entire code coverage report generated for me against my entire app.

Has anyone had any luck getting karma-coverage to work in angular2 with a systemjs test shim?

Thanks